# Id seems to be not existent in django model: that's why no reverse match is found

Tags: django, django-models, primary-key, django-urls

I have a django model for which I am writing my delete view. I get an `django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch` error. That is also logical since when I am trying to debug and I want to output my id with `{{ model.id }}` my view shows me no id at all. When I use the pk it passes in my urls.

My model:

```
class UrlTrack(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
    counter = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)
```

My view:

```
class AnalyticsDeleteUrls(SingleObjectMixin, View):
    model = UrlTrack

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = self.get_object()
        if obj is not None:
            obj.delete()
            return redirect('list_history')
```

My urls:

```
    path('history/delete/urls/<int:id>/', AnalyticsDeleteUrls.as_view(), name="history_url"),
```

My template:

```
  {% for item in url_tracks %}
            <tr>
              <td>{{ item.url }}</td>
              <td>{{ item.counter }}</td>
              <td> <a class="btn btn-danger" href="{% url 'history_url' item.id %}"> Delete </a>
              </tr>
   {% endfor %}
```

Here also my list view:

```
class AnalyticsIndexView(StaffRequiredMixin, ListView):
  template_name = 'analytics_list.html'
  model = UrlTrack
  context_object_name = 'url_tracks'
  queryset = UrlTrack.objects.all()

  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(AnalyticsIndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['object_viewed_list'] = ObjectViewed.objects.all()
    return context
```

Why would the id be non existent? I though django passes that in automatically....?

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: You've set `url` as the primary key

Comment: Absolutely true, I set it as the primary key.... I totally forgot that. But shouldn't I be able to then do {{ item.url }} ? Also this throws me the same error

Comment: I think a url will have / characters which probably get treated differently.  I would make url unique rather than primary.

Comment: good idea... yet I kinda have to make it a primary key, otherwise django doesn't let me migrate: ``` multiple default values specified for column "id" of table "analytics_urltrack"```

Comment: That will be because you're using `makemigrations` and it is asking for a value for `id`.  You'll need to edit the migrations file to give it unique `id`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll actually need to do it in two steps.

First, add `id` to the model, then edit the `makemigrations` file created.  You could try modifying your migrations file to something like this:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models

def set_id(apps, schema_editor):
    UrlTrack = apps.get_model('app_name', 'urltrack')
    count = 1
    for row in UrlTrack.objects.all():
        row.id = count
        count += 1
        row.save()

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('app_name', '0001_previous_migration_name'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='urltrack',
            name='id',
            field=models.IntegerField(),
        ),
        migrations.RunPython(set_id),
    ]
```

Then edit models.py again and make `UrlTrack` unique and `id` primary and run `makemigrations` again

Comment: Henry, my friend, you were right with everything. Thank you so much. I did it as you said, with the exception that I just deleted my migrations and reseted my database. Then I made my url unique and passed instead of the id the pk in my url and my template. Now it works like a charm. Thank you so much for your help!